# knitr inherits variables from a user's environment, even with envir = new.env()

Tags: r, knitr

I've found that a knitr document inherits variables from the user's environment, even if the argument `envir = new.env()` is provided. How can I prevent it from inheriting these variables?

For instance, suppose I wrote a simple .Rmd file using a variable that doesn't exist (`y`), knitted it, and showed the resulting file:

````r
library(knitr)
writeLines(c("```{r}", "y + 1", "```"), "test.Rmd")
knit("test.Rmd", quiet = TRUE, envir = new.env())
# [1] "test.md"
cat(readLines("test.md"), sep = "\n")
# 
# ```r
# y + 1
# #> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'y' not found
# ```
````

Of course, I get an error that the `y` variable doesn't exist, just as I should.

However, if I then define `y` in my own environment, I find I can now refer to `y` in the .Rmd file, even though I give the `envir = new.env()` argument.

````
y <- 3
knit("test.Rmd", quiet = TRUE, envir = new.env())
# [1] "test.md"
cat(readLines("test.md"), sep = "\n")
#
# ```r
# y + 1
# # [1] 4
# ```
````

My understanding was that `envir = new.env()` should have caused the knitr document to be evaluated in a new environment without the `y` variable. This is a problem because it allows knitr documents to be non-reproducible, referring to variables I don't define within the document.

Note that the rmarkdown `render` [documentation](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/rmarkdown/man/render.html) (which is a wrapper around `knit`) specifically says you can use `envir = new.env()`:

> The environment in which the code chunks are to be evaluated during knitting (can use new.env() to guarantee an empty new environment).

However, `render` shows the same behavior as above, for the same reason. Are my expectations (and the rmarkdown docs) incorrect about `envir = new.env()`, or am I using it incorrectly? And is there another way to guarantee a new environment in a document being knitted?

Comment: you could use baseenv instead

Comment: @rawr If I used `baseenv`, I wouldn't be able to load any packages within the knitr chunks. For example, try changing the above lines to `writeLines(c("```{r}", "library(ggplot2)", "qplot(rnorm(100))"), "test.Rmd"); knit("test.Rmd", quiet = TRUE, envir = baseenv())`

Answer (score 10):

[`new.env` has a `parent` argument](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/environment.html) whose default is `parent.frame()` — i.e. the caller. In other words, your new environment inherits all the stuff from your current environment.

You can avoid this by specifying `parent`:

```
new.env(parent = baseenv())
```

Or, if you want to inherit loaded packages:

```
new.env(parent = as.environment(2))
```

And, yes, the `render` documentation is somewhat misleading: while `new.env()` provides a new, empty environment, it’s not entirely decoupled from the caller, and the caller probably almost never wants to use just `new.env()`.

In order to be able to use packages inside a clean environment inherited from `baseenv()`, you need to manually implement the package attachment mechanism because R packages do not support environment isolation by themselves (grrr!). Or you use the [‘box’ package](https://klmr.me/box/), which supports locally attached packages:

````
```{r}
box::use(ggplot2[...])
qplot(rnorm(10))
```
````

The `[...]` declaration causes the package to be attached locally (in the current scope), unlike with `library`.

Comment: I realized that the `parent = baseenv()` solution doesn't allow packages to be loaded within the knitr document. For example, if we changed the above lines to `writeLines(c("```{r}", "library(ggplot2)", "qplot(rnorm(10))", "```"), "test.Rmd")` and `knit("test.Rmd", quiet = TRUE, envir = new.env(parent = baseenv()))` we get an error. ([Much more discussion can be found here](https://github.com/jennybc/reprex/issues/11)). Any ideas how we can fix this?

Comment: @DavidRobinson R packages do not support environment isolation (which is terrible, and one of the reasons for my [“modules” package](https://github.com/klmr/modules). However, it is possible to manually implement that mechanism (after all, that’s what I did for “modules”) and use it here — see updated answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph This is awesome, thanks! This is a really fundamental enhancement. This package needs to make it into CRAN. One potential enhancement: adding `package = as.character(substitute(package))` as a first line in `library_local`. Then both `library_local(ggplot2)` and `library_local("ggplot2")` would both work

Comment: @akhmed Unfortunately somebody else recently “stole” the name of my package on CRAN. :-/ Name clashes really haunt my whole R experience, both inside the console and on CRAN. ;-) So at the moment I have no idea how to get my package into CRAN without renaming it (and I don’t want to do that, since my package is already being used by others and renaming it would break all this code).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I see. One solution could be to take both paths simultaneously? say, 1) keep `modules` on Github for compatibility but also 2) create, say, an `rmodules` fork and submit it to CRAN?

Comment: @akhmed I know I’m four years late but the package [is now on CRAN under the name ‘box’](https://cran.r-project.org/package=box).

Answer (score 1):

While [@Konrad Rudolph's a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32259700/1870254)ttempt to fix the underlying problem (that prevents usage of `envir=baseenv()`) of the R package system's reliance on the `global.env` is very admirable, it might in most cases be more practical to `knit`/`render` R markdown files in a separate process through [`callr`](https://github.com/r-lib/callr) using a function like

```r
render_separately <- function(...) callr::r(
    function(...) rmarkdown::render(..., envir = globalenv()), args = list(...), show = TRUE)
```

or

```r
knit_separately <- function(...) callr::r(
    function(...) knitr::knit(..., envir = globalenv()), args = list(...), show = TRUE)
```

. In your example, these (correctly) throw the expected error:

````r
library(knitr)
writeLines(c("```{r}", "y + 1", "```"), "test.Rmd")
y <- 3
knit_separately("test.Rmd", quiet = TRUE)
#> [1] "test.md"
cat(readLines("test.md"), sep = "\n")
#> 
#> ```r
#> y + 1
#> ```
#> 
#> ```
#> ## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'y' not found
#> ```
````

the `envir=globalenv()` is necessary since the code of the Rmarkdown document would otherwise be executed in the execution environment of the anonymous function which can lead to hard to understand problems ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934716/where-to-define-distribution-function-to-be-used-with-fitdist-fitdistrplus-or), [2](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1365)).

When you hit the knit button in Rstudio something similar happens. Why this is not the default/supported in `rmarkdown`/`knitr`, I don't understand. See theses issues:
(https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1204
https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1673 and this question: [Difference: "Compile PDF" button in RStudio vs. knit() and knit2pdf()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34591487/1870254)