# How do you hide and pass variables in knitr child documents?

Tags: r, knitr

[knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) makes PDFs out of code that is a combination of (in my case) R and LaTEX.  One can assemble a document out of child documents.

As I use it right now, the document is assembled out of global variables, passed into and out of every child document.  This makes it easy to produce spaghetti code.

Is there any way to make R variables "local" to a child doc?  How about make exporting of variables explicit?

I could NULL out every local variable at the end of a child doc, but I wonder if there is some reasonable formal mechanism for loosening code coupling between child documents.

Comment: If you don't want the main document and the child documents to interact, why do you use child documents? If you only want to combine several source files (Rnw) in one LaTeX document, you could `knit` the Rnw files separately and then include them in the main document via `\include{}`.

Comment: I do want them to interact, but in a controlled way. In a normal programming language, one makes functions with parameters and a return value. That allows clarity about the coupling.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`knitr` evaluates all chunks in a common environment (returned by `knit_global()`). This is by design; just like all code in a source file runs in the same environment, all chunks are executed in a common environment. The same applies to [child documents](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/) because they are (in principle, not technically) just a part of the main document, externalized to another file.

This does not necessarily lead to spaghetti code: Nothing prevents users from using functions and other objects to organize code/data in `knitr` documents. But probably few users do so …

So the reason why there are no encapsulation mechanisms for chunks/child documents is that they are *supposed* to share a common environment as they are part of *one* (main) document.

However, it *is* possible to include child documents in a way that gives the user control over the objects child documents and the main document share. The solution is based on the function `knit_child()` which is very similar to the [chunk option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) `child`. The advantage of calling `knit_child()` directly (vs. implicitly via the `child` option) is the possibility to set the `envir` argument which defines "the environment in which the code chunks are to be evaluated" (from `?knit`).

Around `knit_child()`, I wrote the wrapper `IsolatedChild` to simplify matters:

```
IsolatedChild <- function(input, ...) {

  evaluationEnv <- list2env(x = list(...), parent = as.environment(2))
  cat(asis_output(knit_child(input = input, envir = evaluationEnv, quiet = TRUE)))
  return(evaluationEnv)
}
```

Arguments passed to `...` will be available in the child document. (Name them, see example below.) The function returns the environment in which the child document has been evaluated.

Specifying `parent` in `list2env` is crucial and I chose `as.environment(2)` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32259700/2706569). Otherwise `parent` would default to `parent.frame()`, thus exposing objects in `knit_global()` to the child document.

`assign` can be used to make objects returned from `IsolatedChild` available in the global environment.

Note the `cat(asis_output())` construction around `knit_child` which ensures that the output from the child document is correctly included in the main document, regardless of the `results` setting in the current chunk.

Before turning to the example, two final remarks:

- If the child and the main document are not supposed to share *any* objects, this approach is overly complex. Simply `knit` the child document and use `\include{}` to include it in the main document.
- This approach might come with some pitfalls. Especially the enclosing environment of the "isolated child" needs caution because the search path might look different than expected. Note that main and child document share `knitr` options. Besides, both documents could interact via side effects (`options()`, `par()`, opened devices, ...).

---

Below a complete example / demo:

- The chunk `inputNormal` does nothing special, it's just a demonstration of the normal behavior. `inputHidden` demonstrates the use of `IsolatedChild()`, passing two variables to the child document.
- `IsolatedChild()` returns these two values along with a third object created *in* the child.
- `check` demonstrates that the objects passed to/created in the "isolated child" do not pollute the global environment.
- `import` shows how `assign` can be used to "import" an object from the "isolated child" to the global environment.

---

> **`main.Rnw`:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup>>=
library(knitr)

objInMain <- TRUE

IsolatedChild <- function(input, ...) {

  evaluationEnv <- list2env(x = list(...), parent = as.environment(2))
  cat(asis_output(knit_child(input = input, envir = evaluationEnv, quiet = TRUE)))
  return(evaluationEnv)
}

@

<<inputNormal, child="child_normal.Rnw">>=
@

<<inputHidden, results = "asis">>=

returned <- IsolatedChild(input = "child_hidden.Rnw",
                          passedValue = 42,
                          otherPassedValue = 3.14)
cat(sprintf("Returned from hidden child: \\texttt{%s}",
            paste(ls(returned), collapse = ", ")))
@

<<check, results = "asis">>=
cat(sprintf("In global evaluation environment: \\texttt{%s}",
            paste(ls(), collapse = ", ")))
@

<<import, results = "asis">>=
assign("objInChildHidden", returned$objInChildHidden)
cat(sprintf("In global evaluation environment: \\texttt{%s}",
            paste(ls(), collapse = ", ")))
@
\end{document}
```

> **`child_normal.Rnw`:**

```
<<inChildNormal>>=
objInChildNormal <- TRUE # visible in main.Rnw (standard behaviour)
@
```

> **`child_hidden.Rnw`:**

```
Text in \texttt{child\_hidden.Rnw}.

<<inChildHidden>>=
objInChildHidden <- TRUE

print(sprintf("In hidden child: %s",
              paste(ls(), collapse = ", ")))


# Returns FALSE.
# Would be TRUE if "parent" weren't specifiet in list2env().
exists("objInMain", inherits = TRUE)
@
```

> **`main.pdf`:**

[image: main.pdf]

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! I just started learning about environments today. They seem like the right mechanism to pass things.

Comment: Thanks for this amazing post. I would like to be able to share the parent document's environment with children, but I want to isolate the children from each others' environments; is this the correct approach? Before running `IsolatedChild`, should I make a copy of the global environment, and pass that as `parent` in `list2env`?

Comment: @user5359531 I think this depends: What do you expect to happen if one child modifies objects in the parent document's environment? But you should probably ask a new question for that issue, linking to this one.

Comment: I actually ended up implementing this and its working well so far. I didn't intend for children to modify objects, but I'm hoping that R is smart enough to pass a true copy of the parent env namespace to the child and not just a reference.

Comment: @user5359531 I don't think so; environments are passed by reference: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#explicit-envs